# React-testing-libary userEvent Hover does'nt work?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I tried to test if my hover work or not , here's my code to be tested

```js
//styled components + typescript
const Info = styled.div`
    opacity: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index:3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
`
const Container = styled.div`
    flex:1;
    margin:5px;
    min-width:280px;
    height:350px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #f5fbfd;
    position: relative;

    &:hover ${Info}{
        opacity: 1;
    }
`
const ProductItem = ({item}:ProductItemProp) => {
    return (
        <Container data-testid="productContainer">
            <Circle/>
            <Image src={item.img}/>
            <Info data-testid="productInfo">
                <Icon data-testid="productIcon">
                    <ShoppingCartOutlined/>
                </Icon>
                <Icon>
                    <SearchOutlined/>
                </Icon>
                <Icon>
                    <FavoriteBorderOutlined/>
                </Icon>
            </Info>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default ProductItem
```

I want to test if opacity become 1 when I hover the elements

Product.test.tsx

```js
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import ProductItem from "./ProductItem";

test("Check Product Hover", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <ProductItem item={{ id: 7, img: "https://i.imgur.com/aYMvzlX.png" }} />
  );
  const productContainer = getByTestId("productContainer");
  const productInfo = getByTestId("productInfo");

  userEvent.hover(productContainer)
  expect(productInfo).toHaveStyle("opacity:1");

});
```

But the test results still show 0 , so I don't know wha't going on , I know this test is a little bit unnecessary , but I am new to this library and I want to try everything out.

```
- Expected
    - opacity: 1;
    + opacity: 0;
```

Comment: This is not going to address the issue, but you have a typo in your posted sample. The backquotes in your styles are not placed right.

Comment: Have you tried to use `userEvent.hover` to test the hover behavior? Here is the doc: https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event#hoverelement-options

Comment: @tromgy yes originally I tried hover, then it did'nt work , so I read in document that click also trigger hover so I tried click , but it did not work too.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you provided a reproducible example of your setup in a codesanbox or similar, but you might want to add styled-component's **jest integration** tools.

Docs - https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#jest-integration

More docs - https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/blob/main/README.md

Not sure if that's the problem, but you can give it a try.

Ex.:

```
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import ProductItem from "./ProductItem";
import 'jest-styled-components'

test("Check Product Hover", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <ProductItem item={{ id: 7, img: "https://i.imgur.com/aYMvzlX.png" }} />
  );
  const productContainer = getByTestId("productContainer");
  const productInfo = getByTestId("productInfo");

  userEvent.hover(productContainer)
  // expect(productInfo).toHaveStyle("opacity:1");
  // Use this instead - toHaveStyleRule is a custom matcher from jest-styled-components
  expect(productInfo).toHaveStyleRule("opacity", "1");

});
```